# Proper use of the word 'eliminate'

Tags: word-usage

I'm going to carry out a survey about how to equally share the household chores in your family, and my friends and I are thinking of some questions to ask some people.

I would ask:

> If you can eliminate one of the household chores, which chore do you choose?

Now my question is that I don't know whether "eliminate" here is correct. If not, can you correct it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *eliminate* is fine there, but you should use "could" instead of "can":

> If you **could** eliminate one of the household chores, which chore do you choose?

Generally speaking, the word "could" works better than "can" when we start a hypothetical sentence with "if".

That sentence would roughly mean the same as, "If there was one chore that you wish would go away, which one would it be?"